# How to depend on a configuration specific job in order to download its related pipeline artefact

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-devops-pipelines

We are planning to setup a multi-configuration Azure pipeline like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#multi-job-configuration) but our setup is more complicated than that since our pipeline will have multiple jobs with the same matrix strategy. E.g. we will have build and test jobs that follow the same matrix strategy.
Now I have the following challenge to be solved and that is why I need support from you:

Let's say I have two job configurations small and fat and the "small" test jobs needs to pull in the published pipeline artefact from the "small" build job. How would I first declare such a dependency to the "small" job in the azure pipeline yml file and second how can I download the "small" pipeline artefact from the respective "small" build job?

The only idea I have is that I can wait for all the build jobs to be finished first and every build job creates a pipeline artefact with the name of the configuration so that it can be unambiguously referenced.

Please advice on the best solution

Answer (score 0):

I managed the following:

It is not possible to let the "small" test job just wait for the "small" build job. But it is easily possible to wait for all build jobs and then proceed with the test jobs. As part of the build job some pipeline artifacts have "small" in its name so that the "small" test job can then download the "small" build job pipeline artifact.